# CSS Image Hover fading, excluding text

Tags: css, hover

Alright, so I know very little about coding. I've been working for hours to customize a page, and I made substantial progress. However, I have hit a bit of a hiccup once more that has been tiding me over for the past three hours.

I began working with a page code with a large sidebar image. What I wanted to do, and would still like to do, is fade the image so it's darker, with text fading in overtop it. I've managed to get the image to fade as I want it, and I've gotten the text and title of the page to fade in properly. The problem, though, is the opacity.

This is a question I've seen asked many times, but none of the answers have worked for me. Most of the times, I'm seeing people saying that their sidebar is parented to their text. I do NOT think that is the issue with mine, as both the sidebar and the text, called the description in this instance, each have their own

I've gotten the text's opacity to be unaltered by the opacity of the sidebar, however, when I make this change, it messes up the page entirely. The description is off in a random place and the links either disappear or end up on the other end of the page.

I'm not sure what the problem is, and I would LOVE some help as this has been all I've worked on all day aside from watching Game of Thrones. I would love any and all help available, I'm quite desperate at this point and my own patience in regards to digging through the coding has run quite thin. Thank you all in advance for reading!

Here is the coding below:

```
    /*  Sidebar  */

    #sb {
        width: 550px;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 297px;
        background: url({image:Sidebar bg}) no-repeat;
        float: left;
          opacity:1;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 1s ease;
        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #sidebar:hover{
        opacity:.3;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 1s ease;
        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #sb_border {
        float: right;
        width: 50px;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 900px;
        background: {color:Lines};
        padding-top: 250px;
    }


    #title {
        margin-left: 35px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family:josefin sans;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: {color:Blogtitle};
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px {color:Blogtitle textshadow};
        letter-spacing: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
         opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 1s ease;
        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #title:hover {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 1s ease;
        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #description {
        width: 235px;
        margin-left: 35px;
        color: {color:Description};
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 1s ease;
        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #description:hover {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 1s ease;
        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #desc b {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #menu {
        width: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #menu a:link, #menu a:visited, #menu a:active {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: inline-block;
        color: {color:Menulink};
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        width: 50px;
        padding: 4px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
        color: {color:Menulink hover};
        border-bottom: 1px solid {color:Menulink hover border};
        background: {color:Menulink hover bg};
    }

    #pagination {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #pagination a:link, #pagination a:visited {
        margin: 5px 0;
    }









    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        {CustomCSS}


    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Sidebar -->


<div id="sb">


<div id="sidebar">


    <div id="title">{Title}</div>
    <div id="description">{Description}</div>

   </div>


<div id="sb_border">

    <div id="menu" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <a href="/">home</a><br />
        <a href="/ask">askbox</a><br />
        {Block:ifShowLink1}<a href="{text:link1 url}">{text:link1}</a><br />
        {/Block:ifShowLink1}
        {Block:ifShowLink2}<a href="{text:link2 url}">{text:link2}</a><br />
        {/Block:ifShowLink2}
        {Block:ifShowLink3}<a href="{text:link3 url}">{text:link3}</a><br />
        {/Block:ifShowLink3}
        {Block:ifShowLink4}<a href="{text:link4 url}">{text:link4}</a><br />
        {/Block:ifShowLink4}
        {Block:ifShowLink5}<a href="{text:link5 url}">{text:link5}</a>
        {/Block:ifShowLink5}
    </div></div>

    <div id="pagination">
        {block:Pagination}
        {block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">«</a>&nbsp;
        {/block:PreviousPage}
        {block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}">»</a>
        {/block:NextPage}
        {/block:Pagination}
    </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle or provide us the URL to work with. Also try to be more concise with the questions and only post relevant code.

Comment: The URl of the page with my edits?

As for the code, I'm not sure what there is the problem. That's the thing: I have no idea what's causing the issues when I change the code. 

In the clearest way I can think of, my question is this: 

How can I change the opacity of the sidebar without it effecting the opacity of the description and title within? Without the change messing up the page.

Comment: i also dont knwow what a jsfiddle is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ I agree you need to trim down your question. Do you have an example somewhere online that you can point to?

Comment: I've trimmed the coding, and as for an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish, I have one here: http://viwan-demo.tumblr.com/naturalis

What I'm attempting to do is on that page, on the left. Ideally, I'd like it as close to that as possible, complete with the Title and Sub Title at the bottom. At this point, though, I'll accept anything.

The difference in what I'm trying to accomplish, though, rests primarily in the size of the sidebar image.

Comment: I've also made a bit of progress, though it might ultimately prove to be irrelevant. I managed to separate the two elements, though now the description is seemingly anchored to the top right corner, and despite any changes I've made with the margin values, it will not move. 

I'm also having an issue with hovering. Hovering over the description causes it to fade in, but nothing happens with the background image. I explored the usage of pointer-events, but have had no luck. 

I digress, though. The equivalent of what I'm trying to accomplish is on the page I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with positioning.  You need to position `<div id="description">...</div>` so it lays over top of `<div id="sidebar">...</div>`.

You also don't need a `:hover` property for "sidebar" only for "description".

I made a JSFiddle example for you: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/csJ6N/3/) and hover over the image to see the effect.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That worked like a dream! There is still a problem, though. I attempt to reposition the text, but it still won't move. I've tried using margin-bottom and margin-left

Comment: Well it looks like your text is being imported as part of some sort of template (PHP perhaps?) so I would need more info to help you position your text. It could be pulling it's styles from a different stylesheet that is part of the template, it could be importing additional HTML elements like <h1> & <p>, It's hard to say. You could always get rid of the `{text}` element and put your own text inside the div like I did on my fiddle. Please do me a favor and vote up my answer or "accept it" (green check mark) if you feel it appropriate. It will help me build reputation points. Cheers!